# (jQuery) A click event is sometimes not attached to its element - seems tied to Developer Tools being open

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, onclicklistener, addeventlistener, developer-tools

I have been trying to locate the source of a problem for a few hours now, and I am beginning to think my bug suffers from the observer effect!

In summary:

- There are checkboxes on my page
- Once the entire page has finished loading, attach a listener to each checkbox

---

```
var myModule = (function() {
    var myFunction = function() {
        console.log("Do something");
     }

    var setUpTogglers = function() {
        var dict = {
          "#checkbox1": "div.div1",
          "#checkbox2": "div.div2"
        };

        $.each(dict, function(i, elem) {
           var toggler = $(i);
           var fader = $(dict[i]);
           toggler.on('click', function() {
               myFunction(fader);
           });
        });
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            setUpTogglers();
         }
    };
})();



$(window).on("load", function() {
    myModule.init();
});
```

---

This is a pretty straight forward task (or so I thought, anyways.) My problem arises from the click event being listened for only SOME of the time.

Here is a case where it does not work:

- Navigate through the site to the page with the checkboxes
- Inspect the checkbox element with the Developer Tools
- Examine the 'Event Listeners' tab
- My element does not appear under click root

Here is a case where it does work

- Open Developer Tools
- Navigate through the site to the page with the checkboxes
- Examine the 'Event Listeners' tab
- My element does appear under click root

I've tested it a number of times in various ways. I've loaded/refreshed the page with Developer Tools open and not had a listener; I've refreshed the page with CTRL-F5 (and Developer Tools not open) and HAD a listener; I've set a breakpoint where the listener gets attached and sometimes the listener gets attached, sometimes it does not.

In all the testing that I've been doing for the last hour, however, the listener has gotten attached when the page has been loaded or refreshed with the Developer Tools window open. This leads me to believe it's some sort of load order issue? I really have no idea where to even start debugging this. If anyone has any suggestions, it would very much be appreciated.

tldr:
Event listener getting attached to checkbox when developer tools is open, but **not always** getting attached otherwise. What could be some reasons for this happening?

Note: I am using Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

based on the code provided i would suggest refactoring this as the hard coded dictionary and the each loop seems dodgy and strange to me.

Why not have something like this? This also makes your code testable and easier to debug using the console sinse you are tagging google dev tools etc in your question.

```
var myModule = (function() {

    function BindEventLister(jquerySelector, fader){

           $(''+jquerySelector+'').on('click', function() {
               myFunction(fader);
           });
     }

    var myFunction = function() {
        console.log("Do something");
     }


    var setUpTogglers = function() {

         BindEventLister("#checkbox1","div.div1");

         BindEventLister("#checkbox2","div.div2");
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            setUpTogglers();
         }
    };
})();



$(window).on("load", function() {
    myModule.init();
});
```

Im not testing/running this code im just typing out a rough idea quickly to help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try out something similar to this and let you know if it works.

Comment: lol also since you are hard coding the dictionary why not scrap all the code and just bind an event to the divs your want straight? $(''#checkbox1).on('click', function() { myFunction("div.div1"); });$(''#checkbox2).on('click', function() { myFunction("div.div2"); });

hehe if you are only binding to so few items why do you need this code?

Comment: I only gave a couple items for the purpose of this question. There are more than two key value pairs. It was set up with iteration to avoid code duplication.

Comment: okay well i hope you can come right with a more straight forward and testable approach like the one i have provided rather than hard coding and looping over dictionaries :-)

Comment: Sorry, I stepped away from this for the weekend. Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. My guess is that it's due to some part of the DOM not being visible yet. I will investigate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that an external library is conflicting with my script file. I thought that wouldn't happen because I've wrapped my code in a module, but I must not be namespacing correctly.

When I remove this external library, the code behaves as expected.